# How to observe a boolen field with RxJava

Tags: android, observable, rx-java

In my class `Foo` I have a boolen field. When the field changes I will react on this change in my class `Bar`
How can I implement this with RxJava in Android?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to create class `Foo` with subject inside

```
class Foo {
    var booleanField: Boolean = false
    set(value) {
        field = value
        observable.onNext(value)
    }
    val observable = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(booleanField)
}
```

Then you have to observe that subject inside `Boo` class

```
class Boo(val observable: BehaviorSubject<Boolean>) {
    var booleanField: Boolean = false
    var disposable: Disposable? = null

    fun startObserve() {
        disposable?.dispose()
        disposable = observable.subscribe {
            booleanField = it
        }
    }

    fun finishObserve() {
        disposable?.dispose()
        disposable = null
    }
}
```

If you have to run it just create Foo and pass it's subject to Boo:

```
val foo = Foo()
val boo = Boo(foo.observable)
boo.startObserve()

foo.booleanField = true //boo is changed to true too
```

now if you change `foo.booleanField`, `boo.booleanField` will change too.
If you need, you can run startObserve in constructor to start it immidiatly after creating instance.
May be you have to create `BehaviorSubject` somewhere else and just pass to both classes using DI.
And do not forget to unsubscribe after work is done.